# C# Event Handler trigger multiple times, however need to handle it once in 10 secs

Tags: c#, windows

I got a condition, were I have listener which listens for a event.

Trying to do something like below, event handler may receive multiple events, however i need to merge them in one and trigger once.

```
private static void QueueRequestChanged()
{
     // This may get 1 or 10 events here.
     // want to keep wait for 10 seconds.

     // trigger one event to handle it further
}
```

I am trying to do this, to avoid dead lock situation. Any suggestion on approach will help.

Thank you.

Comment: Use a timer with an interval of 10 seconds. This method should Start the timer and the timer handler should be your "one event to handle it further".

Comment: Reactive Extensions is perfect for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thank you for response. was curious will it be an issue in difference machine depending on configuration?

Comment: Reactive Extensions is perfect for this sort of thing. Do you have any link or example that will help..

Comment: Reactive Extensions, for example: [Observable.Throttle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229400(v=vs.103).aspx)

Comment: Here is the Reactive Extensions [repo](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET) and here is the [book](http://www.introtorx.com/uat/content/v1.0.10621.0/00_Foreword.html). Don't panic - if you know LINQ you will be using reactive extensions effectively in a short time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into Reactive Extensions (Rx): https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/

It makes these kind of things easy if you know LINQ:

```
using System.Reactive.Linq;
...

System.Reactive.Linq.Observable
    .FromEventPattern<RoutedEventArgs>(btn, "Click")
    .Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)) //take the last event for every 10 seconds
    .Subscribe(_ => { MessageBox.Show("clicked!"); });
```

The above sample code bundles all `Clicked` events raised by a WPF `Button` named "btn" during the last 10 seconds and handles only the latest one by displaying a `MessageBox`.

You need to change `RoutedEventArgs` to whatever the type of your `EventArgs` is, "Click" to the actual name of the event and "btn" to the name of the object that raises the event.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the following code, which will not put your thread in a wait state:

```
private const Timespan c_maxTime = new Timespan(0, 0, 10);
private static DateTime? s_lastValidEvent;
private static object s_lockObject = new Object();

private static void QueueRequestChanged()
{
     lock (s_lockObject)
     {
          if (!s_lastValidEvent.HasValue || (DateTime.Now - s_lastValidEvent.Value) > c_maxTime)
          {
              // Do whatever the event is supposed to trigger
              s_lastValidEvent = DateTime.Now;
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, i have did as below, and seems working fine for me.

```
     var events = 0
     private static void QueueRequestChanged()
    {           
        events++;           
        Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith(t => Trigger());
    }

    private static void Trigger()
    {
               if(events > 0)
               {
                    events = 0;
                    // do code here
               }
    }
```

Any better suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.